# How to return MongoDB document to express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

After I connect to my db I am able to get my documents from a collection but I am not sure how am I supposed to return it and use it in a route.

```
var findDocuments = (db, callback) => {
  var collection = db.collection(category)

  collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log(docs);
    // return "docs" array
    callback;
  })
}


app.get("/route", (res, req) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    console.log("Connected successfully")
    findDocuments(db, () => {
      // I WANT TO RETURN THE "docs" ARRAY SO I CAN USE IT HERE
      // The ".render()" is for my templating engine
      // res.render('field', {field: docs});
      db.close();
    })
  }); 
})
```

I want to be able to pass the "docs" array to the render so I can use the information on my ejs (Embedded JavaScript Template Engine) template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can accept the docs variable inside your callback and then pass them when you call it. Also because the callback is defined inside the scope of the request, you can access the response method from there

```
var findDocuments = (db, callback) => {
  var collection = db.collection(category)

  collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log(docs);
    // return "docs" array
    callback(docs);
  })
}


app.get("/route", (res, req) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    console.log("Connected successfully")
    findDocuments(db, (docs) => {
      res.render(docs)
      db.close();
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an errors saying that res.render is not a function ( also tried with res.send(docs) and I got the same error)

Comment: can you "cosole.log(res)" to check wich methods are available on your res variable. Also can you provide information about which server are you using? is it express ?

Comment: I console.log(res) and I got a lot of things back, and yes I am using express

Answer (score -1):

You can use `res.json(...)` to send the response to your request.

Try this:

```
app.get("/route", (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    console.log("Connected successfully")
    findDocuments(db, (docs) => {
      res.json(docs)
      db.close();
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: I still get the error saying that res.json is not a function, I don't think I am allowed to use the res parameter inside the MongoClient.connect

Comment: You need to change the argument of get route, from `(res,req)` to `(req,res)`. `req` is the first argument, and `res` is second argument. I have updated my answer, kindly retry.